# Change Order of the CTreeCtrl item by Drag and drop, MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an application which has CTreeCtrl which shows all the folders of the specific drive, I want to change the order of the folder in the same CTreeCtrl by means of Drag n Drop. How can it be done. I have implemented the code for getting the folder name in the CTreeCtrl but wondering how can i change order by means of Drag & Drop.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you mean you want to sort the contents of the tree differently?

Comment: No i dont want to sort the content i want to let the user ,have freedom to order their folder as they want, using drag and drop. So just change the order of the items.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is sample code vailable at [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535368/Versatile-Tree-Control). Just use google.

Comment: I have refered the code from code project and also able to drag and drop folder, but whenever i drop in middle of the tree it doesnt get add to that place instead it gets added at last of the tree list. I want the item to be added at the place where it is dropped.