# Drag & Drop in MFC Tree Ctrl to change the position of tree item

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, tree, drag-and-drop

I'm new to MFC and started learning it from past few weeks. I'm stuck at a place where I want to drag and drop tree item to re-position them with in the same parent node. For example:

Parent1

->child1

->child2

->child3

after re-positioning (Dragging child1 and dropping below child3) the order should be in following order:

Parent1

->child2

->child3

->child1

I tried the example mentioned in [Codeproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242298/change-order-of-the-ctreectrl-item-by-drag-and-drop-mfc/) but it didn't serve my requirement.

I also tried [Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53596/Tree-Control-Offering-Drag-and-Drop-Folder-Auto-ex) but this has small issue like when an item is dropeed to last it is added as a child node to last item but not as sibling node. Please help me on this. My main requirement is reordering of tree items. Thanks in advance. :) :)

Comment: I'm able to partially solve the problem with second link provided, but when the last node has children and if it is in expanded state, if I'm trying to drop a node below last node it is dropped as child to last node but not as a sibling to the last one. Can any one solve this issue? or any valid reason if it cannot be solved? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should check that the tree item handle for the item you are dragging points to the correct "parent" before adding/moving the tree item.